# Application Slowness | No CPU load on server

Tags: performance

We have 5 Applications running on one Virtual server (EC2) on the AWS cloud. We have MySQL Database configured for all applications also on the same server.

Out of these 5 Applications, 4 are working fine. But there is one Application which we launched last week which causing a slowness issue.

Though we can put that one application on a different server and we can configure a separate database for that server too but my question is,

The landing page loads faster but when we log in it and access any resources it getting slow. We check our server CPU load at that time which is below 30%.

We want to understand where is the bottleneck? In application source code or in Database connectivity?

Is there any tool or anything that we can use to find the root cause of this issue?

Any Suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell what and all the applications and databases are running?And please share the server configurations as well.

Comment: Log in to MySQL Command Prompt as root and run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; when slow to detect QUERY that is slow.  Do you have Slow Query Log enabled with long_query_time as .5 (one half second) to log queries taking longer than this limit?  If not, consider reviewing this helpful URL - https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/08/09/logging-and-analyzing-slow-queries-in-mysql

Comment: In, SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  I can see my application DB (application having slowness) where command sleep time keeps incrementing.  The slow query log is disabled.

Comment: Could you post just 1st page of SFPL?  If you need assistance with enabling your Slow Query Log, let us know.  Once you have slow query log enabled, post ONLY the last 10 listed slow queries for guidance/assistance after 24 hours of SQL being available.

Comment: Yes, I enabled this Slow query log. The problem is, Post login the Application when we browse courses it takes too much time.  The request is able to find a database but I guess the file size of courses is huge so it taking time to load, so are any settings in the MySQL database that I could do so large files can able to load quickly?